# Simular toque y deslice en android

Tags: android, app, macros, click

Estoy intentando hacer una app que (sin root) 'haga click' en un lugar específico de la pantalla (con coordenadas x, y) sin yo tener que tocar nada.

¿Hay alguna función (o código algo más complejo) que simule un toque en la pantalla en unas ciertas coordenadas?
¿Es posible simular un 'trayecto' (me refiero a un 'swipe', a que el el 'mouse' se deslice por la pantalla de una manera que yo le indique)?

He buscado por muchos sitios pero no he conseguido encontrar ni siquiera lo de simular un toque en la pantalla.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Esa clase de comportamiento se logra usando MotionEvent, si lo que necesitas en hacer un swipe, deberas generar 3 eventos, el MotionEventActions.Down, MotionEventActions.Move y MotionEventActions.Up, con el orden correcto y los parametros bien puestos deberia andar.

Aca un ejemplo:

```
public void deslizar(final View view, final int fromX, final int fromY, final int toX,final int toY){

  //Tab down
  post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), (int)MotionEventActions.Down, fromX, fromY, 0));
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        event.recycle();
    }
  });

  //Tab Move
  postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, fromX, fromY, 0)
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        event.recycle();
    }
  }, 100);
  postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE, toX, toY, 0)
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        event.recycle();
    }
  }, 200);

  //Tab Up
  postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.Obtain(SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), SystemClock.UptimeMillis(), (int)MotionEventActions.Up, toX, toY, 0)
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        event.recycle();
    }
  }, 300);
}
```

ejecuto los eventos con postDeleay para que no ejecuten todos al mismo tiempo y se pueda apreciar el swipe.